# How to create a button like the one in the attached image

Tags: flutter, flutter-design

Please tell me how to create a button like the one in the attached image. I can create round buttons but could not gloss them.

```
ElevatedButton(
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
onPressed){},Child:Text(''),)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a straightforward way to create such a button using standard material Widgets. I would suggest you either use an image for this button or you can draw something like this using `CustomPainter`, you can learn more about it here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html